# Is it possible to load the effective address in SI/DI with the string and a variable?

Tags: masm, emu8086, dosbox

```
DATA SEGMENT
    STR DB "HELLO!!$"
    LEN DB ?
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
START: MOV AX,DATA
       MOV DX,AX
       MOV BL,STR+1
       MOV LEN,BL
       LEA SI,STR+LEN
       CODE ENDS
       END START
```

Here, I want to just to show an example which I wrote the above code, actually, I am trying this technique to implement in code palindrome of a string.
But, however, it shows the following error:
[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9ASn.png)

Hence, I want to know how can I implement it in some other way to achieve it??

Comment: rather than make `LEN` a variable make it a constant and compute it with something like `LEN EQU $-STR` . You may also have to use a different label name than `STR` as it could be seen as a reserved word.

Comment: Don't use picture of text.. Instead use code block in question body and paste contents.